# How to put a value into html code in tapestry?

Tags: jquery, tapestry

On the client-side:

```
$('#hidden-medium-id').val( $(this).data('medium-id'));
```

tml Tapestry:

```
<t:textfield t:id="hidden-medium-id value="value-required"></t:textfield>
```

any idea? the value must be in a `<t:from>`

regards

---

its working:

tml-part:

```
<t:hidden t:id="hiddenMediumId" id="hidden-medium-id" value="hidden"/>
```

java part:

```
@Property
private String hidden;
```

java script-part:

```
 $('#hidden-medium-id').val( $(this).data('medium-id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a syntax error '.**. Missing Quote**

```
<t:textfield t:id="hidden-medium-id" value=" 
                                   ^---  Missing here
```

If that does not work change the selector and see if that works

```
$('[id*="hidden-medium-id"]')
```

Comment: hi - but what about the value? value is required in tml - if i write value="" -> syntax error - thx